# Django: serving user uploaded files

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django and Python.I want to display a link to my files stored in my `static` folder.Here is the required code from `settings.py`:

`MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"`

When I access these files through my `admin` I get the following url displayed in my browser:

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/filename.pdf

Hence what I tried is to give a link to the file in my HTML code :

`<a href="/{{instance.docFile.url}}/">File</a>`

But instead of displaying `http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/filename.pdf` it just displays `/media/filename.pdf` which results in an error.

Adding `localhost:8000/` before `{{instance.docFile.url}}` also didn't work.

Why isn't this working?What is the correct way to display link to my files?

Let me know if anything else is required.Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is coming because your file is not stored in `media`.it is stored in `static` but your database store `media` URL. change your MEDIA_ROOT (given below) and try to upload one more time

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Don't put slash
:

```
<a href="{{instance.docFile.url}}">File</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

in your **urls.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

in your **settings.py**

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'uploads')
MEDIA_URL = '/uploads/'
```

Then in your **template**

```
<a href="{{instance.docFile.url}}">File</a>
```

If you want know refer the docs [Manage static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/)

Answer (score 2):

Please see the Django [setting MEDIA_ROOT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#std:setting-MEDIA_ROOT) documentation to better understand what your trying to do.

First MEDIA_ROOT and STATIC_ROOT must have different values.

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

See [static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/) documentation for more details.

Second, You need to add these settings to your base urls.py.

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

If you want to use **{{ [MEDIA_URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#std:setting-MEDIA_URL) }}** in your templates, add **'django.template.context_processors.media'** in the **'context_processors'** option of **TEMPLATES** in settings.py.

At the top of your **HTML** page add **{% load static %}** then to display your media:

```
<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ docFile }}" alt="test">
```

Please take your time with the Django Documentation, trust  me it will help and also checkout the [File upload settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#file-upload-settings)